# Using a Treeview to display information

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a `treeview` which has a list of countries, i also have a `textbox` with a description about each country how can i change the text in the description depending on which node is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`AfterSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of your `TreeView`:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private TreeView treeView1;
    private TextBox textBox1;
    // ... shortened example

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView1.AfterSelect += treeView1_AfterSelect;
        //...
    }

    private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string description = string.Empty;
        TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        if (node != null)
            description = // determine the text from your country data

        textBox1.Text = description;
    }
}
```

---

I normally set the `Tag` property of the `TreeNode` to the corresponding model instance. So if you have a `Country` class as this:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I'd add `TreeNodes` like this:

```
Country country = new Country { Name = "SomeCountry", Description = "description" };
TreeNode nextNode = new TreeNode(country.Name);
nextNode.Tag = country;
parentNode.Nodes.Add(nextNode);
```

And your `AfterSelect` handler could look like this:

```
    private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = (treeView1.SelectedNode?.Tag as Country)?.Description ?? string.Empty;
    }
```